# Alternative to d3.scaleQuantize?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 charts.

We're currently creating a chart based on the [d3 Calendar View](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318).

The issue I'm having is with the colors. It uses `d3.scaleQuantize()`, which apparently divides the domain by the number of colors, and then assigns a color to each section. In other words, every color has the same range.

So in the following case, anything between 1&2 is Blue, 3&4 is Black, 5&6 is Red, 7&8 is Yellow, and 9&10 is Green.

```
var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
.domain([1,10])
.range(["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Yellow", "Green"]);
```

In our particular case, I need to set the colors depending on the range. For example, anything that's between 1&3 is Blue, 4&6 is Black, and anything over 6 is Red.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

I'm including all the code as reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var Cell = url.searchParams.get("Cell");

var width = 960,
  height = 136,
  cellSize = 17;

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range(["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Yellow", "Green"]);

var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(2017, 2018))
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

var rect = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeDays(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.getDay() * cellSize;
  })
  .datum(dateFormat);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeMonths(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", pathMonth);

var url = "http://Server/Service1.svc/GetData/" + Cell;

d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  //populating data since i don't have the file

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.datekey;
    })
    .map(data);

    rect.filter(function(d) {
      return ("$" + d) in nest;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { 
      return color(nest[("$" + d)][0].Sales);
    })
});

function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
    d0 = t0.getDay(),
    w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
    d1 = t1.getDay(),
    w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize +
    "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize +
    "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize +
    "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0 +
    "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If your requirement is that simple and concise, why not write your own scale function? basically it just takes a value and returns a color.

Comment: I'm new to d3 charts and my javascript is very limited. I wouldn't even know where to begin writing a scale function.

Comment: `function scale(x) { switch(true){ case x<=3: return "blue"; case x<= 6: return "black"; default: return "green"; } }` Hope I didnt miss any parenthesis.

Comment: This probably does not work for creating legends, but it will work with the usual mark generation.

Comment: I would like to include your code with the rest of the example as reference. Can that be done? I'm including the actual code in my question.

Comment: @rbhat the idiomatic scale in your case is `d3.scaleThreshold`. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference:

If the scaling function is that simple and is not needed in automatic axis/legend creation, one can simple write the function themselves. So in this case, this could look something like this:

```
function scale(x) { 
  switch(true){ 
    case x<=3: return "blue"; 
    case x<=6: return "black"; 
    default:   return "green"; 
  } 
}
```

Note, that a scaling function just maps from your "measured" value to a displayed value. Sometimes there is no need for the more sophisticated functions of d3.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this question having an already accepted answer, I'm writing this one for the future readers.

Given the behaviour described by OP (*"I need to set the colors depending on the range, anything that's between 1&3 is blue, 4&6 is black, and anything over 6 is red"*), the correct scale here is a **threshold scale**.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleThreshold):

> Threshold scales are similar to quantize scales, except they allow you to map **arbitrary subsets** of the domain to discrete values in the range. The input domain is still continuous, and divided into slices based on a set of **threshold values**. (emphases mine)

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([4, 6])
  .range(["blue", "black", "red"]);


console.log("color for 1 is :" + color(1))
console.log("color for 2 is :" + color(2))
console.log("color for 3 is :" + color(3))
console.log("color for 4 is :" + color(4))
console.log("color for 5 is :" + color(5))
console.log("color for 6 is :" + color(6))
console.log("color for 200 is :" + color(200))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In a threshold scale, if the range has `n` values the domain must have `n - 1` values. So, in the demo above:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([4, 6])
    .range(["blue", "black", "red"]);
```

Anything less than 4 will be mapped to `blue`. Between 4 and less than 6 will be mapped to `black`. And more than 6 will be mapped to `red`.

This scale is nice because you can quickly define a lot of thresholds. For instance:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 80])
    .range(["white", "yellow", "lime", "green", "blue", "orange", "red"]);
```

Also, it has convenient methods, like `invertExtent()`.

PS: The scale in the demo doesn't start at 1, as you asked. For that, just add `1` as the first value in the domain and add a new value in the range, specifying what (if any)  is the color for values smaller than 1.